# Angular line chart getting points value on click

Tags: angular, charts

I have a web with several angular charts.

I am trying to click on the line one so I can get the value of the point I am clicking at that moment.

It is supposed to be super simple, but I wont get values no matter what.

HTML

```
<canvas id="myLine" class="chart chart-line" chart-data="lineChart.data" chart-labels="lineChart.labels" chart-options="lineChart.options" chart-series="lineChart.series" chart-click="chooseMonth" chart="myLine"></canvas>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$scope.chooseMonth = function(points,evt)
{
    console.log(points[0].value);

};
```

As far as I know, is this simple but with this code I just get "Undefined".

The object I get has lots of data inside, but not the values or labels or anything relatable at all.

If I just print the points

```
console.log(points);
```

[image: Result]

Nothing there... No values anywhere.

What I am doing wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try points[0].labels;
or
points[0].data;

Comment: points[0].labels returns undefined. The second option throws this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

You can get the index value from

```
var index = points[0]._index;
```

and then use this value to get data from the `xScale` and `yScale` as

```
var xval = points[0]._xScale.ticks[index];

var yval = points[0]._yScale.ticks[index];
```